# Issue in downloading a file through an HTTP Get in java

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a application which is accessible using URL : http://test:10123

And this application requires a login and used to generate reports.

So if you access the below link in browser it downloads the report  with the report_id=123

http://test:10123/servlet/XXXServlet/Report123.csv?reportID=123

I have written a main method which uses the apache httpclient-3.x for downloading the file using the URL. But its not working. Please see the code below:

```
        String website="http://test"; int port=10123; String resource="servlet/XXXServlet/Report123.csv?reportID=123";
        GetMethod getMethod = null;
        byte[] responseBody = null;
        HttpClientParams params = new HttpClientParams();
        params.setSoTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(params);
        client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("XXXX",8080);
        client.getHostConfiguration().setHost(website, port, "http");
        getMethod = new GetMethod(resource);
        int statusCode=client.executeMethod(getMethod);
        System.out.println(statusCode);
        responseBody = getMethod.getResponseBody();
```

Please help.

Comment: Status code 400 means `The request had bad syntax or was inherently impossible to be satisfied.`

Comment: But what could be the problem. Is the code having some issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `String website="http://test";` to `String website="test";`
Since this is then feed to `setHost`, which expects the host name only.